# Show/Hide Android keyboard having connected an usb keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

On an activity I have two EditText. One that must not show the Android Keyboard and an other that must show it. I have already tried to implement the following code to show the keyboard:

```
EditText txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(txtName, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Also I have tried a lot of other examples that I found.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)this.getSystemService(Service.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```

For show:

```
imm.showSoftInput(ed, 0);
```

For Hide

```
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(ed.getWindowToken(), 0);
```